# Trouble with logging and Junit test within Android Junit project

Tags: android, logging, junit

I have an Android project in which I have a few activities as well as some regular java code, all of which I would like to be able to test using Junit.  I have created an Android Junit project alongside my regular android project and included Junit 4 libraries so that I can run both android junit tests and regular junit tests.

Everything was working fine, i.e. Junit tests were running and passing, until I tried to add logging into my main project using SLF4J for Android.  Now whenever I try to run a Junit test I get an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/util/Log
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.util.Log
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this error is occurring? If there is a better way to set up my project to make both Junit and Android Junit testing possible, I'm all ears!

Comment: I actually prefer Robolectric for Android unit testing: http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/ Not sure though if it will help your actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'll look into using Robolectric.  But like you said I'm not sure if it will address this issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running tests as JUnit on your host's JVM you will not be able to access Android classes like `android.util.Log`.
`android.jar` provides only stubs.

Comment: I fixed this by adding a "android.util" package to my test project and then copied the `Log.class` signatures (from Open Declaration, F3) into a `Log.java`, then bam, no more errors in my JUnit test. This worked for me since I'm just making some middlewear and aren't actually using any of the Android specific classes. It would probably be too much work if your code references lots of the `android.` namespace, but in that case, you would probably want to test in an AVD anyway.